# gremlin filtering out edges based on time and fetch max value

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am having list of edges between two vertices having time as edge property key.
Eg:
**A --> B ( time=t1,age=20),  A-->B (time=t2,age=30)** ...

I need to fetch edges greater than the given time and take the max value of property '**age**'

Code Example :

```
 val end_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - duration
 val r = graph.V().has(ID, name).outE.filter { it: Edge =>
      (it.property(time).value() > end_time)
    }
 println("r.values("age").max().headOption().get)
```

this returns in **Option[Byte]** format.

Is there any better way to do this. Also i need the value in integer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should avoid using lambdas in general:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-lambdas

You can filter the edges based on a specific minimal value with the following query:

```
g.V().has('ID', 'a').outE().where(values('time').is(gt(end_time)))
```

If you now want to get the maximum value of an edge property like age for those edges, you can simply add that to the query:

```
g.V().has('ID', 'a').outE().where(values('time').is(gt(end_time))).values('age').max()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my query is how to get the max value of **age** property with all edges having timestamp greater than the given time. Modified the query like this `graph.V().has(ID,'A').outE().where(_.value("time").is(P.gt(end_time))).value("age").min().head` which returns me Byte. I need it as Integer . How can i convert to int.

Comment: I edited my answer to also include how you can get the maximum age of the filtered edges. But I can't really help you with your problem of getting the correct return type. Which version of Gremlin are you using?

Comment: Just noticed that you tagged your question with 'scala', so your problem may be specific to Gremlin-Scala.